# Reload select options

Tags: angular

I have the two select inputs: Country and City.
I want to have cities changed after I change country, but they are only changed after I open city select twice.
It seems like after I choose country, ngFor cycle is not run immediately.

How can I get changes of cities options immediately after I select a country?

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="country">Country</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="country" name="country" #countrySelect>
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">{{country.name}}</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="city">City</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="city" name="city" #citySelect [(ngModel)]="publisher.cityId">
    <option *ngFor="let city of cities"
            [hidden]="countrySelect.value != city.countryId"
            [value]="city.id">
      {{city.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `change` directive.
Here is an example of how you can do it. First you must build a custom function to filter cities per country

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="country.id">{{country.name}}</option>
</select>

 <select class="form-control" id="city" name="city" #citySelect [(ngModel)]="publisher.cityId">
<option *ngFor="let city of filteredCities"
        [hidden]="countrySelect.value != city.countryId"
        [value]="city.id">
  {{city.name}}
</option>
```

```
allCities = [];
filteredCities = [];
allCountries = [];

onChange(country) {
   filteredCities = [];//You empty filterdCities
   //Then filter allCities variable according to selected country values and add values to 
}
```